# Java Matcher format for the string #xxx#

Tags: java

I have to get the string which contains in between the symbols #(String)#.

How can I achieve it?

Comment: Is there anything you have done to try to solve this problem? We will be more willing to answer your question if you tell us what you have tried so far. (Helpful links for asking better questions: [ask], [FAQ])

Comment: I tried for [\\s\\u00A0]{2,}|[[\\s\\u00A0]&&[^ ]].But not working

Comment: Just a little bit of research will definitely solve your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a regex like this:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("#(.*?)#");
Matcher m = p.matcher(yourString);
System.out.println(m.find() ? m.group(1) : "No match");
```

Or, you could split by `#`:

```
String[] tokens = yourString.split("#");
System.out.println(tokens.length >= 3 ? tokens[1] : "No match");
```

These will both get the first token, i.e. if you had `this#is a#string#it is stringy#okay` it would return `is a`. If you need it to match from the first `#` to the last, you could modify the regex by removing the `?` (lazy matching symbol).

If you want to get all tokens, just print all of the values in the second example instead of just the one at the second index.

Comment: @Pshemo that would print every other match, which is probably not what the OP wants

Comment: Then consider `if(m.find())`.

Answer (score 2):

Try `indexOf` and `substring` methods of [String class.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html)

```
String str = "#(String)#";
String result = str.substring(str.indexOf("#")+1 , str.lastIndexOf("#"));
```